# Changing value of GIT_SSH for tortoiseGit

Tags: git, svn, ssh, tortoisegit

I want to use tortoiseGit to check out a SVN repository via SSH.

It fails every time because the SSH command can't be executed. Apparently the reason is, that a custom SSH command gets invoked, which contains a user name and a password. I used tortoiseSVN before to access a repository via SSH and tried to submit the authentication credentials (the same as in the custom command) in the command line, but since that didn't work I switched to key-based authentication. This is actually what I would like to do with git too, but before I can do this, I obviously have to change the SSH command.

I was curious, how my old credentials could be transmitted to the server and finally found in the tortoiseGit settings the button "Show environment variables". There I could see two variables named GIT_SSH and SVN_SSH both containing the same, wrong command. So I looked for these environment variables, but apparently they don't exist. I tried to create them, but git keeps using the old ones.

I assume that in some kind of script, these variables are defined, before git is launched, but after hours of searching, i could not find anything. I also reinstalled git, toritoiseGit and tortoiseSvn and tried to delete all data, but after installing everything again, git would still use the wrong command.

The actual output is (which I got after selecting "Git clone" - "From SVN Repository" :

```
git.exe svn clone "svn+ssh://username@puttyconfig/path/to/my/repo"  "C:\Path\to\Repo\on\Filesysem" -T trunk -b branches -t tags

WARNING: --prefix is not given, defaulting to empty prefix.
This is probably not what you want! In order to stay compatible
with regular remote-tracking refs, provide a prefix like
--prefix=origin/ (remember the trailing slash), which will cause
the SVN-tracking refs to be placed at refs/remotes/origin/*.
NOTE: In Git v2.0, the default prefix will change from empty to 'origin/'.
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Path/to/Repo/on/Filesysem/.git/
No such file or directory: Error in child process: exec of 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe -I username -pw password' failed: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 310



git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (1794 ms @ 06.11.2014 16:17:30)
```

And the command in '' is actually the exact same string as I find in GIT_SSH and SVN_SSH.

Comment: Please can you provide the actual command you're running (with the URL hidden/changed if you wish) and the error message you get when running it?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.

I uninstalled tortoiseGit, Git and tortoiseSVN. After that I searched my harddrive for any configuration file that might be left and actually found plenty. After that I searched the registry for any old keys and again found plenty. Apparently, SVN_SSH and GIT_SSH were story in the registry and not in the environment variables (despite the fact that they are called environment variables...).

After reinstalling everything and trying around for some time, I was able to check out the repository. So apparently the whole problem was cause by people that are unable to write a uninstaller, that is actually capable of removing the program completely and not only deletes some binaries...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include parameters into the SVN_SSH environment variable for usage with Git (for Windows).

Create a putty configuration and store the username there so that you do not need to use CLI parameters. The password is not necessary to be posted as parameter as the predefined ASKPASS tool can ask for it.

or

Create a wrapper application which starts Tortoise(Git)Plink with the proper parameters which hands stdin and stdout over to Tortoise(Git)Plink.

Comment: Oh I was actually trying to do exactly this, I just did not find a way to change the wrong value in SVN_SSH

Answer (score 1):

just in case someone else gets here, I got a similar error message in combination with using Git Extensions on Windows:

> failed: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 310GitExtensions\PuTTY\plink.exe

The fix was to set the git_ssh environment variable to the 8.3 format:

```
set git_ssh=c:\progra~2\gitextensions\putty\plink.exe
```

"progra~2" in my case is the shortname for "program files(x86)", you can get the shortname of a directory via dir /x on the command line

seems like spaces in the path aren't properly handled